# How to find the occurrences of any word with more than two vowels in a file using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble figuring out how to find all words that have 2 or more vowels in them. So far this is what I have but when i run it, it don't give me any output. I appreciate the help.

```
import re

def main():

in_f = open("jobs-061505.txt", "r")
read = in_f.read()
in_f.close()
for word in read:
    re.findall(r"\b[aAeEiIoOuU]*", read)
    in_f = open("twoVoweledWordList.txt", "w")
    in_f.write(word)
    in_f.close()

print (word)
main()
```

My apologies if this is not the right format.

Comment: Consider using `\w` and more than one vowel in the same word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for word in read:  <--- iterating over chars in "read"!
    re.findall(r"\b[aAeEiIoOuU]*", read)  <-- using read again, discarding result
```

your iteration and pattern usage do not align. Plus, you don't use the result.

Consider processing the file line by line etc.

```
twovowels=re.compile(r".*[aeiou].*[aeiou].*", re.I)
nonword=re.compile(r"\W+", re.U)
file = open("filename")
for line in file:
    for word in nonword.split(line):
        if twovowels.match(word): print word
file.close()
```

Comment: actually `read` is a string, whole contents of the file; and Python is strongly typed, so your comment is out of point here.

Comment: Your're right, he slurped the whole file before, then is iterating over the characters now... so the typing problem is in the for loop - it's a `for char in string` loop, not a `for line in file` loop, but due to the lack of type information in the source, the runtime doesn't help detecting this mistake.

Comment: What lack of information? You can always detect type in Python and type of object cannot be changed, contrary to languages like C/C++. That is pretty strong type system in my opinion... Now you are trying to derive some non-sense from the fact that there is not 'char' type in Python, because single character is just string of len 1. Please stop. What you are doing can confuse newbies and give them wrong impression what strong/weak and dynamic/static type systems are.

Comment: It may not be your opinion of what is "strong", but Python *is* using duck typing, not strong typing. Python doesn't warn you of errors that e.g. Java with a strong variable type system *would* have warned you about. Please stop.

Comment: see duck typing in C: http://libcello.org/; if you are not satified [with official](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language) [classification on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info), please take case to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I don't care about SO "official classification". **Fact is, Python didn't help finding this bug** (and Java would have). That is all the user needs, not "official classification". Sorry to ruin your *fanboying*. I use Python a lot, but the one thing I miss often is explicit typing, it would have saved me a lot of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) function  to find all the words which contains atleast two vowels,

```
>>> s = """foo bar hghghg ljklj jfjgf o jgjh aei
bar oum"""
>>> re.findall(r'\S*?[aAeEiIoOuU]\S*?[aAeEiIoOuU]\S*', s)
['foo', 'aei', 'oum']
>>> re.findall(r'\w*?[aAeEiIoOuU]\w*?[aAeEiIoOuU]\w*', s)
['foo', 'aei', 'oum']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a='hello how are you"
[ x for x in a.split(' ') if len(re.findall('[aeiouAEIOU]',x))>=2 ]
```

Modification in your code

```
import re

def main():

in_f = open("jobs-061505.txt", "r")
read = in_f.read()
words = [ x for x in re.findall('\w+',read) if len(re.finall('[aeiouAEIOU]',x))>=2 ]
print words
```

int he above code `'read()` will read entire file as string. re.findall('\w+',read) will give you list of word. if length of list is greater or equal to two. it will be stored as list.
now you can do whatever with the output now.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to use this command:

```
re.findall('\S*[aAeEiIoOuUyY]\S*[aAeEiIoOuUyY]\S*', str)
```

Where **str** is the string in which you're looking for word with two or more vowels.

---

**REGEX explanation:**

**\S** - it means 'every non-white character'

**[aAeEiIoOuUyY]** - it represents every of the characters in brackets (so 'a' OR 'A' OR 'e' etc.)

**a*** - it means that there can be arbitrary number of occurrences of the character preceeding * ( 'a' in this case )

---

**EXAMPLE:**

String:

```
str = "aaa bbb abb koo llk tr"
```

Python code:

```
import re
re.findall('\S*[aAeEiIoOuUyY]\S*[aAeEiIoOuUyY]\S*', str)
```

Output:

```
['aaa', 'koo']
```